# How to run Apex anonymous code from Visual Studio Code

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, visualstudiocode

Is it possible / How would I run a block of Apex anonymous code from Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the command palette, if you type "sfdx ex" you will be offered this if you have some Apex text selected:

```
SFDX: Execute Anonymous Apex with Currently Selected Text
```

or this:

```
SFDX: Execute Anonymous Apex with Editor Contents
```

if you don't.

Not too sure why there is also this [.apex file thing](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/441) too. As the project is open source you can see open issues, all issues, pull requests etc here https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues.

Comment: As far as I know, the .apex file extension is simply to add code highlighting (and perhaps other IDE language features? though no intellisense on my test) for saved scripts--rather than saving them in the project as a .txt file, for instance.

Answer (score 10):

For all those command liners, you can also use [`force:apex:execute`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_apex.htm)

```
sfdx force:apex:execute -u MyConnectedOrg
```

Start typing straight into the terminal or copy/paste your code of interest.  Ctrl+D will execute the code

#### Update Feb 2024

[`sf`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_top.htm) is the new preferred way to use CLI commands, and you can use the following as an equivalent to the example above:

```
sf apex run -o MyConnectedOrg
```

See all the options for [`sf apex run` here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_apex_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_apex_run_unified)

Answer (score 2):

1. Create new file (Cmd + N).
2. Select `Anonymous Apex` as language for the file.

[image]

3. SFDX: Execute Anonymous Apex with Editor Contents (I made it as Hot Key (Cmd + Enter))

[image]